# Как узнать какие элементы затронул запрос к БД?

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net

Пишу приложение SQL-Тренажёр на WPF. 
На странице решения задания выводится само задание, форма для ввода запроса и DataTable  с выводом результата. Я реализовал проверку запросов SELECT и вывод ошибки в случае исключения или неправильного набора данных.
Т.к. одного и того же результата можно добиться разными запросами, то сравнивать нужно именно результат. Но как мне получить результат команд INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE, а точнее элементы, которые были ими затронуты (в случае INSERT -- добавлены), если я заранее не знаю, к какой таблице БД выполняется запрос?
Например,

- Ожидаемый запрос:  `DELETE FROM pc WHERE price < 500`
- Запрос пользователя: `DELETE FROM pc WHERE price > 500`

Запрос пользователя написан верно с точки зрения языка, но будут удалены неверные элементы, а это ошибка. Каким образом можно получить элементы, затронутые двумя этими запросами и сравнить между собой для проверки? Или есть другой способ?

Методы для взаимодействия с БД:

```
public static object IsCorrectQuery(string userQuery, TrainSQL_DAL.Task task)
        {
            object res = null;

            List<string> testDBList = null; // Список имён тестовых БД

            try
            {
                using (var context = new TrainSQL_Entities())
                {
                    int shemeID = context.TestDatabases.FirstOrDefault(x => x.dbID == task.dbID).ShemeID;
                    testDBList = (from x in context.TestDatabases
                                  where x.ShemeID == shemeID
                                  select x.dbName).ToList();
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

            if (testDBList == null || testDBList.Count == 0) return null;

            string mainDB = testDBList.FirstOrDefault(x => !char.IsDigit(x.Last()));
            if (mainDB != null)
            {
                var tryGetTable = GetQueryTable(userQuery, mainDB);
                DataTable showTable = null; // DataTable для вывода
                string allCorrect = null; // Сообщение об ошибке
                if (tryGetTable is DataTable)
                {
                    showTable = (DataTable)tryGetTable;
                    for (int i = 0; i < testDBList.Count() && allCorrect == null; i++)
                    {
                        allCorrect = CheckQuery(userQuery, task.RightAnswer, testDBList[i]);
                    }
                }
                else allCorrect = (string)tryGetTable;

                res = new object[] { showTable, allCorrect };

            }

            return res;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Получение таблицы, которая будет показана пользователю
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sql">Запрос</param>
        /// <param name="dbName">Имя БД, к которой идёт обращение</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static object GetQueryTable(string sql, string dbName)
        {
            string connectionString = $"Data Source=DESKTOP-5D0552Q;Initial Catalog={dbName};Integrated Security=True";
            DataTable dataTable = null;
            string error = null;
            try
            {
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection);

                    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(ds);

                    dataTable = ds.Tables[0];

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch(InvalidCastException ex)
            {
                error = "Состояние объекта блокирует вызов метода (InvalidOperationException)!\n" + ex.Message;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                error = "Ошибка обращения к БД!\n" + ex.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               error = "Ошибка при выполнении запроса!\n" + ex.Message;
            }

            if (error != null) return error;
            else return dataTable;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Проверка полученного запроса на таблицах
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userQuery">Запрос пользователя</param>
        /// <param name="rightQuery">Правильный запрос</param>
        /// <param name="dbName">Название </param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string CheckQuery(string userQuery, string rightQuery, string dbName)
        {
            string result = null;

            string connectionString = $"Data Source=DESKTOP-5D0552Q;Initial Catalog={dbName};Integrated Security=True";
            try
            {                
                using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    DataTable userTable = new DataTable(); 
                    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(userQuery, connection);
                    SqlDataReader userReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    userTable.Load(userReader);
                    userReader.Close();

                    DataTable rightTable = new DataTable();
                    command = new SqlCommand(rightQuery, connection);
                    SqlDataReader rightReader = command.ExecuteReader();
                    rightTable.Load(rightReader);
                    rightReader.Close();

                    result = AreTablesTheSame(userTable, rightTable);

                    connection.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (ObjectDisposedException ex)
            {
                result = "Попытка выполнить оперции над удалённым объектом (ObjectDisposedException)!\n" + ex.Message;
            }
            catch (InvalidCastException ex)
            {
                result = "Недопустимое приведение/преобразование (InvalidCastException)!\n" + ex.Message;
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                result = "Ошибка SQL!\n" + ex.Message;
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
            {
                result = "Состояние объекта блокирует вызов метода (InvalidOperationException)!\n" + ex.Message;
            }                 
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                result = "Ошибка dремени выполнения!" + ex.Message;
            }

            return result;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Проверка полученного результата с ожидаемым
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="userTbl">Результат пользователя</param>
        /// <param name="rightTbl">Ожидаемый результат</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string AreTablesTheSame(DataTable userTbl, DataTable rightTbl)
        {
            string error = "";
            int dif = 0;

            if (userTbl.Columns.Count != rightTbl.Columns.Count)
            {
                error += "\nНеверное количество столбцов. ";

                dif = Math.Abs(userTbl.Columns.Count - rightTbl.Columns.Count);

                if (userTbl.Columns.Count > rightTbl.Columns.Count)
                {
                    error += "Больше на " + dif;
                }
                else error += "Меньше на " + dif;
            }

            if (userTbl.Rows.Count != rightTbl.Rows.Count)
            {
                error += "\nНеверное количество элементов. ";

                dif = Math.Abs(userTbl.Rows.Count - rightTbl.Rows.Count);

                if (userTbl.Rows.Count > rightTbl.Rows.Count)
                {
                    error+="Больше на " + dif; 
                }
                else error+="Меньше на " + dif;

            }


            if (error == "")
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < userTbl.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    for (int c = 0; c < userTbl.Columns.Count; c++)
                    {
                        if (!Equals(userTbl.Rows[i][c], rightTbl.Rows[i][c]))
                            error = "\nВыбраны не правильные элементы";
                    }
                }
            }

            return error == "" ? null : error;
        }
```

Страница задания: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Первое - зачем тебе это вообще нужно. Второе - почему нельзя просто привести запросы к одному виду и сравнить их. Третье - можешь расписать подробно и понятно, и со скринами

Comment: @KuzCode, отредачил

Comment: Раз список заданий заранее определен, значит и правильные результаты известны заранее. Тогда под каждую задачу нужно заблаговременно подготовить либо `view` либо `stored procedure`, кот. будет отдавать временную таблицу. Далее пользовательский ввод вы применяете и сравниваете с верными результатами из временной таблицы с помощью [одного из этих способов](https://codingsight.com/different-ways-to-compare-sql-server-tables-schema-and-data/). Да и пользовательские действия нужно тоже отправлять во временные таблицы.

Comment: @Bulson, результаты не известны заранее. Известны запросы, которые дают правильные результаты

Comment: Предложу несколько вариантов: 1. написать запрос `select` с тем же `where`; 2. использовать триггеры, в которых изменённые (удалённые) строки (или их id) заносить, например, во временную таблицу для последующего сравнения; 3. использовать [output clause](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: `Известны запросы, которые дают правильные результаты` - да, я это и подразумевал, под результатами, создаете хранимки под верные запросы кот. отдают временные таблицы, а потом их сравниваете с таблицами полученными через применение пользовательских запросов.

Answer (score 0):

Как и всегда возможностей реализовать вашу задумку масса, творчества можно приложить уйму.
Как я понял это какое-то учебно-тренировочное приложение, что бы проверить правильность усвоения подопытным материала в вопросе баз данных. Что ж, как вам такой алгоритм: (ИМХО) найдутся критики, просьба не в комментах токсинить, а предложить свой вариант)))

1) Сделать "семантическое ядро" программы, с которым будут все запросы пользователя сравниваться (то есть создать шаблон запросов);

2) Создать дубликат базы данных куда будут отправляться запросы юзера, а на оригинальную БД будут отправлять ваши каноничные, результат же будет просто сравниваться, после чего будет происходить заветный бэкап баз до исходного состояния.

Comment: зачем создавать дубликат, если изменения можно вносить в транзакции и не сохранять в БД? И как сравнивать результат? Перебирать все таблицы?

Comment: вариант со сверкой запросов вам не нравится? перебор таблиц и сравнение результатов не такой уж затраный в рамках обучающих БД и нынешних мощностей вариант. Опять же, как вам будет удобнее